# How to pass HTML with json and ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to display the output from the database using JSON Encode function and Ajax. But, I'm getting difficult on how to pass the html element "" and the php "eg." variable that show data from the server.I want the output to be displayed using json and ajax request.Thanks.

Here's my codes

```
 //js
  function mpo() 
 {
     $.ajax({
         url: "main.php",
         cache: false,
         success: function(html){
             $("#show_div").html(html);
         }
     });
 }


//php

$bu = "<div class='main' style='margin-left:" .($level*60). "px'>";     
$bu = "<div class='main_one'>";
$bu = "<div class='main_User'>" .($same[2]) . "</div>";
$bu = "<div class='main_Msg'>" .($same[3]) . "</div>";
$bu = "<div class='main_Date'>" . ($same[4]) . "</div>";
$json  =array('bu'=>$bu);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dataType : 'html'`  with this you don't requied to json encode

```
//js
  function mpo() 
 {
     $.ajax({
         url: "main.php",
         cache: false,
         dataType : 'html'
         success: function(html){
             $("#show_div").html(html);
         }
     });
 }

//php

$bu = "<div class='main' style='margin-left:" .($level*60). "px'>";     
$bu = "<div class='main_one'>";
$bu = "<div class='main_User'>" .($same[2]) . "</div>";
$bu = "<div class='main_Msg'>" .($same[3]) . "</div>";
$bu = "<div class='main_Date'>" . ($same[4]) . "</div>";

echo $json;die;
```

Comment: I am also agree with **jeroen**. If you want to do it only json encode way then jeroen way is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 things:

1. You (probably...) need to parse the json.
2. You need to get the right element from the parsed object.

To have jQuery parse the json automatically, you can set the dataType:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "main.php",
     dataType: 'json',
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ set the data type of the returned data
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
         $("#show_div").html(html.bu);
                             ^^^^^^^ get the correct element
     }
 });
```

Comment: How can I do In this way?                           eg  "success:function(data){
                            var content = '';
                            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                            $.each(data, function(i, post) {
                                content += '<div>' + post.post_title + '</div>';
                            });

                            $(content).appendTo("#results");
                    },
"